# How to pass parameters from a batch file

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, command-line-arguments

I have a batch file that execute my console application. I need to pass a parameters inside the console but I don't know how to pass it and how to add it into the main()
The parameters are projectsId

This is what I have into my batch file:

```
@echo off
start "C:\Users\testUser\Documents\console.exe %2345867162 %4756473622
```

This is my code from my console application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    data();
}

string ProjectID = "";

byte[] MyBinFiles = db.GetResponse3(ProjectID);    

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(MyBinFiles);
```

Comment: Those arguments are stored in the `args` array in `Main`. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: did you check the values of `args[0]` and `args[1]`?

Comment: yes, so I need to pass the array with all the parameters into the main? something like this into the main so its going to take the paramaters from the batch file?

Comment: sorry I forgot to include the main example var arg = new string[] { "arg0", "arg1"};

Answer (score 1):

> [The Main method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx) is the entry point of a C# console application or
>   windows application. (Libraries and services do not require a Main
>   method as an entry point.). When the application is started, the Main
>   method is the first method that is invoked.
>
> You can send arguments to the Main method by defining the method in
>   one of the following ways: 
>   `static int Main(string[] args)`
>   `static void Main(string[] args)`

read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx)

parameters that are passed to the main method of your program are accessible through `args` array in `Main` method. use them the way you want

Comment: Hi, I understand what are you referring, but I still don't know what I need to pass when the batch file will be executed in way that the console application recognize that the parameters that are inside the batch file are being referring to the parameter inside the console application which in this case is the ProjectId

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using the arguments of the Main method, you can use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx